# How to include external Javascript in BIRT Scripting Data Source

Tags: javascript, birt

I am writing a Scripted Data Source in my BIRT report. Is it possible to include/invoke external JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add js file with external JavaScript in

> Report Property Editor - Resources - Javascript Files: - Add File...